# how to add multiple charts and multiple series with excel in C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I'm trying to programmatically add 2 Excel charts to a workbook. Each chart is on a separate sheet.This code, and everything I try, adds the first chart, Ch0, with the two series, A1-A401,B1-B401,ok. BUT the second chart, Ch1, always adds a chart with 4 series,A1-A401,B1-B401,C1-C401,D1-D401.
Can someone tell me and how to make Ch1 only have it's 2 series?

```
    public void MakeCharts()
    {
        Series[] oSeries = new Series[2];
        Chart[] ChartObject = new Chart[2];
        SeriesCollection[] oSeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection[2];

        ChartObject[0] = book.Charts.Add();
        ChartObject[0].ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
        ChartObject[0].Name = "Ch0";
        oSeriesCollection[0] = ChartObject[0].SeriesCollection();
        oSeries[0] = oSeriesCollection[0].NewSeries();
        oSeries[0].Values = workSheet.get_Range("A1", "A401");
        oSeries[1] = oSeriesCollection[0].NewSeries();
        oSeries[1].Values = workSheet.get_Range("B1", "B401");

        ChartObject[1] = book.Charts.Add();
        ChartObject[1].ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
        ChartObject[1].Name = "Ch1";
        oSeriesCollection[1] = ChartObject[1].SeriesCollection();
        oSeries[0] = oSeriesCollection[1].NewSeries();
        oSeries[0].Values = workSheet.get_Range("C1", "C401");
        oSeries[1] = oSeriesCollection[1].NewSeries();
        oSeries[1].Values = workSheet.get_Range("D1", "D401");
    }
```

Comment: I got it working. This adds multiple series tomultiple cahrts. The trick is to series.Delete() before every Chart.Add()

Comment: I got it working. This adds multiple series tomultiple cahrts. The trick is to series.Delete() before every Chart.Add()